# Creating new array with unique key while mapping through given array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am struggling with an array that i need to convert into a new array with unique keys. I have an array called 'mondayAvailability' which looks like this:

```
[
 {
   id: 1,
   from_time: '09:00',
   to_time: '10:00'
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   from_time: '16:00',
   to_time: '17:30'
 },
]
```

I need to extract 30-minute time slots based on the values of 'from_time' and 'to_time' of each item in the array, and create a new array called 'mondayTimeLabels', which will store these slots. Each time slot will be an object containing a unique key so the new array looks like this:

```
[
 {
   key: '1',
   slotTime: 09:00 AM,
   disabled: false
 },
 {
   key: '2',
   slotTime: 09:30 AM,
   disabled: false
 },
 {
   key: '3',
   slotTime: 10:00 AM,
   disabled: false
 },
 {
   key: '4',
   slotTime: 04:00 PM,
   disabled: false
 },
 {
   key: '5',
   slotTime: 04:30 PM,
   disabled: false
 },
 {
   key: '6',
   slotTime: 05:00 PM,
   disabled: false
 },
 {
   key: '7',
   slotTime: 05:30 PM,
   disabled: false
 },
]
```

I could achieve most of what i desire with the code below. However the problem with the code below is that it doesn't return unique keys when the original array length > 1. So how could i change my code to ensure that the new array mondayTimeLabels will end up with items with a unique key? Thanks in advance.

```
let mondayTimeLabels = [];
let startTime;
let endTime;
let arrayLength;
let slotTime;

mondayAvailability.map(item => {
  startTime = moment(item.from_time.substring(0,5), 'hh:mm')
  endTime = moment(item.to_time.substring(0,5), 'hh:mm')
  arrayLength = endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes') / 30;
  slotTime = startTime;

  for (let x = 0; x <= arrayLength; x++) {
    slotTime.add(x === 0 ? 0 : interval)
    mondayTimeLabels.push({
      key: x,
      slotTime: slotTime.format('hh:mm A'),
      disabled: false
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just keep a counter for the keys outside of the loop, something like:

```js
let mondayAvailability = [{
    id: 1,
    from_time: "09:00",
    to_time: "10:00",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    from_time: "16:00",
    to_time: "17:30",
  },
];
let mondayTimeLabels = [];
let startTime;
let endTime;
let arrayLength;
let slotTime;
let key = 1;

mondayAvailability.map((item) => {
  startTime = moment(item.from_time.substring(0, 5), "hh:mm");
  endTime = moment(item.to_time.substring(0, 5), "hh:mm");
  arrayLength = endTime.diff(startTime, "minutes") / 30;
  slotTime = startTime;

  for (let x = 0; x <= arrayLength; x++) {
    slotTime.add(x === 0 ? 0 : 30, "minutes");
    mondayTimeLabels.push({
      key: String(key),
      slotTime: slotTime.format("hh:mm A"),
      disabled: false,
    });
    key++;
  }
});
console.log(mondayTimeLabels);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use maps index option to create unique key, like

```js
let mondayTimeLabels = [];
let startTime;
let endTime;
let arrayLength;
let slotTime;

 mondayAvailability = [
 {
   id: 1,
   from_time: '09:00',
   to_time: '10:00'
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   from_time: '16:00',
   to_time: '17:30'
 },
]

mondayAvailability.map((item,index) => {
  startTime = moment(item.from_time.substring(0,5), 'hh:mm')
  endTime = moment(item.to_time.substring(0,5), 'hh:mm')
  arrayLength = endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes') / 30;
  slotTime = startTime;
  unikey = index.toString();
  for (let x = 0; x <= arrayLength; x++) {
    slotTime.add(x === 0 ? 0 : 30);
    mondayTimeLabels.push({
      key: unikey+x,
      slotTime: slotTime.format('hh:mm A'),
      disabled: false
    })
  }
})
console.log(mondayTimeLabels)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

may be you need to define how many minutes the diff interval between these data, momen have that fungtion, you could use some thing like `slotTime.add(moment.duration(30, 'minutes'))`, have you tried this,not an efisien way but i think it's good starting point.

```
let key = 1;
mondayAvailability.map(item => {
    startTime = moment(item.from_time.substring(0,5), 'hh:mm')
    endTime = moment(item.to_time.substring(0,5), 'hh:mm')

    arrayLength = endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes') / 30;
    slotTime = startTime;
    for (let x = 0; x <= arrayLength; x++) {
        if(x === 0){
            mondayTimeLabels.push({
                key:key,slotTime:startTime.format('hh:mm A'),disabled:false
            })
        }else if(x === arrayLength){
            mondayTimeLabels.push({
                key:key,slotTime:endTime.format('hh:mm A'),disabled:false
            })
        }else{
            // add 30 minutes between start and endtime.
            let add = slotTime.add(moment.duration(30, 'minutes'));
            mondayTimeLabels.push({
                key:key,slotTime:add.format('hh:mm A'),disabled:false
            })
        }
        key++
    }

})

console.table(mondayTimeLabels)
```

here is the result, when i tried that snipset.

```
┌─────────┬─────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ (index) │ key │  slotTime  │ disabled │
├─────────┼─────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│    0    │  1  │ '09:00 AM' │  false   │
│    1    │  2  │ '09:30 AM' │  false   │
│    2    │  3  │ '10:00 AM' │  false   │
│    3    │  4  │ '04:00 PM' │  false   │
│    4    │  5  │ '04:30 PM' │  false   │
│    5    │  6  │ '05:00 PM' │  false   │
│    6    │  7  │ '05:30 PM' │  false   │
└─────────┴─────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Rolled back. Do not copy.